# Node.js -liquibase is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, liquibase

I am trying to connect my database in Node.js but I am getting the error `liquibase is not a function`. I did install the module using `npm install liquibase`. Why am I getting this error?

```
const liquibase = require('liquibase');

liquibase({
  changeLogFile: 'resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml',
  url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'admin'
})
.run('<action>', '<action-params>')
.then(() => console.log('success'))
.catch((err) => console.log('fail', err));
```

### New error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-liquibase'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\fabio\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\LiquibaseNode\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabio\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\LiquibaseNode\index.js:1:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\fabio\\OneDrive\\Ambiente de Trabalho\\LiquibaseNode\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/liquibase) it should be `require('node-liquibase')` or `import { Liquibase } from 'node-liquibase';`

Comment: So I downloaded the wrong package?

Comment: No you just didn't read the doc :)

Comment: Made the change but now I am getting another error

Comment: I don't know exactly what's wrong, but nowhere in the doc of this package I see `liquibase({ changeLogFile : ...})`. I see `new LiquibaseTS(myConfig)`. Might be worth casting an eye over the documentation, and make sure it's the right package indeed.

Comment: Can it be an error in the module installation?

Comment: If NPM didn't output any during the installation, then no

Comment: Maybe not a real 'error' but a mistake in where/how it was installed is what I'm leaning towards here.

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a link to the docs for Node errors.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_module_not_found)

> MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>
> A module file could not be resolved while attempting a require() or import operation.

**My guess is that `node-liquibase` is not installed in your application's `node_modules` directory, and/or is not installed globally on your host machine.**

---

Other commenters have already caught some of the issues I was going to mention, and I would also encourage taking a look at the [documentation for using it in JavaScript files](https://github.com/liquibase/node-liquibase#javascript). There were a few bugs in your original post that are resolved by making sure you're importing the right package and using it correctly.

If you're still having issues, here are the steps I would take if I were in your position:

- Verify that there is a `node_modules` directory in the root of my Node application
- Verify that `node_modules/liquibase` also exists in the root of my Node application
- Verify that whatever instance of Node I'm invoking is 'where' I expect it to be (i.e. "Am I invoking the 'right' application?")

Here's an example of the tree structure for the [Node Liquibase Sandbox example repo](https://github.com/tabuckner/node-liquibase-sandbox). This will show what a working `node-liquibase` consuming project could look like:

```
.
├── README.md
├── assets
│   └── img
├── changelog.xml
├── db-start-up.sh
├── index.ts
├── node_modules
│   ├── @types
│   ├── liquibase
│   ├── tslib
│   └── typescript
├── package.json
├── testing.js
├── tsconfig.esm.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

In this example there's `package.json` file that defines all of the metadata about your Node application, and as a direct 'sibling' there's a `node_modules` directory that has this application's installed version of `node-liquibase`.

---

**TLDR;** Basically your app is asking for `node-liquibase` but Node can't find it.